# How do I avoid printing the first node in my linked list?

Tags: c++, function, class, struct, linked-list

I'm trying to create a linked list that has 2 data types and a function that inserts nodes. But in order to insert nodes, I have to create at least 1 empty node first.

linked list struct

```
struct receipt{
    string name;
    double price;
    receipt* link;
};
```

function that inserts a node at the end of the list

```
void insert(receipt** head_name_ref, string new_name, double new_price)
{
    receipt* new_name_node = new receipt();
    receipt *last = *head_name_ref;
    new_name_node->name = new_name;
    new_name_node->price = new_price;
    new_name_node->link = NULL;
    if (*head_name_ref == NULL)
    {
        *head_name_ref = new_name_node;
        return;
    }
    while (last->link != NULL)
    {
        last = last->link;
    }
    last->link = new_name_node;
    return;
}
```

function that print the list

```
void printList(receipt* n){
    while(n!=NULL){
        cout<<"Name: "<<n->name<<'\t'<<" ";
        cout<<"Price: "<<n->price<<'\t'<<" ";
        cout<<endl;

        n=n->link;
    }
}
```

main function

```
int main(){
    receipt* head = NULL;
    head = new receipt;
    insert(&head, "item", 23);

    printList(head);
    return 0;
}
```

here is a picture of the output https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ss02.png

Comment: Please explain why you "have to create at least 1 empty node first". (If it's because of `receipt *last = *head_name_ref;`, have you considered not doing that until you need `last`?)

Comment: `receipt *last = *head_name_ref;` is perfectly fine. But `last->link` is not. You have to check if `last` is a `nullptr` and then you don't need a dummy first element.

Comment: PS: if you insert to the end of a list then it's very likely a simple list is not the right data structure. You should have a `struct ListHead`  that keeps track of the start and end of the list so you can insert at the end in `O(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

First note that when `struct receipt` is constructed, `price` and `link` will be **uninitialized** (`std::string name` will be default constructed to an empty string, but `double` and pointers do not have such a default initialization). This problem will manifest with this line in `main`:

```
head = new receipt;
```

(the problem does not manifest when you create `new_name_node` because you manually initialized it after the allocation).
Therefore you should better handle `struct receipt` initialization. The minimum would be something like this:

```
struct receipt {
    std::string name;
    double price{ 0 };
    receipt* link{ nullptr };
};
```

You can consider to add a custom constructor.

**Now to answer you question:**
The question title is *how to avoid printing the first node*.
To do this you just have to skip one node before starting the loop.
Add the following at the beginning of `printList`:

```
if (n != nullptr)
{
    n = n->link;
}
```

However, "solving" the problem like this is **not** a good idea.

Having a "dummy" first node in a linked list is not the ideal design.
I suggest you redesign your code to avoid it. You can search the web for typical linked list implementations to get some ideas. Then the issue of printing (while skipping a node) will not arise at all.

On a side note: better to avoid `using namespace std` - see here [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 0):

Consider that in a more complex program you would have much more than simply a main function.  When creating a data structure you have to store a pointer or reference to an object in some way that other functions can receive or access the pointer. For something this simple a global variable or instance of a struct containing the attributes of the list would suffice. Simply initialize the head to 0 and create the functions needed to manage that global object. Upon the first instantiation of the node, simply assign the head to that pointer.

You've already created a struct that represents a node.  Now create another one that represents the list which contains nodes.  Within that struct you'd want attributes such as a head that pointers to the first node object or null if it is empty.  You can give it a default constructor.

Since this looks like an assignment I'm only giving you some hints and not a complete example, purposefully.

```
struct SinglyLinkList {
   receipt* head;
   SinglyLinkList() : head(0) {}
   ~SinglyLinkList() { // code to iterate and destroy all node objects }
   // now define copy constructor and assignment operators if you want or delete those
   
   // possibly some methods to add, remove, print nodes
   void print();
   add(receipt* r); // could overload to insert at a position
   remove(size_t n); // remove nth receipt or overload to remove by some other factor
   void   removeAll();
   receipt
};

// somewhere above the main function you could just instantiate a global list
// Within the main function you may call methods that operate on the 
// list and call its methods, or define other global functions if you 
// prefer that the list be defined only with the attributes
SinglyLinkList list;  // default constructed with head = 0 or head = nullptr if you prefer
```